# TypeError: 'set' type is unordered

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the common elements from all the columns of a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
                   0                 1                 2
0   PPRFP.1T22AD0010  PPRFP.1T22AD0010  PPRFP.1T22AD0010
1   TRRFF.1T22AD0033  TRRFF.1T22AD0033  TRRFF.1T22AD0033
2   TRRFF.1T22AD0004  TRRFF.1T22AD0004  TRRFF.1T22AD0004
3   TRRFF.1T22AD0038  TRRFF.1T22AD0038  TRRFF.1T22AD0038
4   TRRFF.1T22AD0025  TRRFF.1T22AD0025  TRRFF.1T22AD0025
..               ...               ...               ...
91  PPRFP.1T22AD0028  PPRFP.1T22AD0028  PPRFP.1T22AD0028
92  HTRFF.1T22AD0004  HTRFF.1T22AD0004  HTRFF.1T22AD0004
93  TRRFF.1T22AD0034  TRRFF.1T22AD0034  TRRFF.1T22AD0034
94  PPRFP.1T22AD0040  PPRFP.1T22AD0040  PPRFP.1T22AD0040
95  TRRFF.1T22AD0007  TRRFF.1T22AD0007  TRRFF.1T22AD0007
```

like the following:

```
        comon_dict = set.intersection(*df_last1.agg(set))
```

earlier it was working fine but when all the columns have same elements it shows the following error:

> TypeError: 'set' type is unordered

Full error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\inventory\views.py", line 325, in get
    dic = set.intersection(*df_last1.agg(set))
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 8550, in aggregate
    result = op.agg()
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 715, in agg
    result = self.obj.apply(self.orig_f, axis, args=self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 8740, in apply
    return op.apply()
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 688, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 815, in apply_standard
    return self.wrap_results(results, res_index)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 841, in wrap_results
    return self.wrap_results_for_axis(results, res_index)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 909, in wrap_results_for_axis
    result = self.obj._constructor(data=results)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 614, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 464, in dict_to_mgr
    return arrays_to_mgr(
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 124, in arrays_to_mgr
    arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 589, in _homogenize
    val = sanitize_array(
  File "C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\multitennant_v2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 559, in sanitize_array
    raise TypeError(f"'{type(data).__name__}' type is unordered")
TypeError: 'set' type is unordered
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: What does your desired output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
set(df.values.ravel())
```

Output:

```
{'PPRFP.1T22AD0028', 'TRRFF.1T22AD0025', 
'PPRFP.1T22AD0010', 'TRRFF.1T22AD0007', 
'HTRFF.1T22AD0004', 'TRRFF.1T22AD0034', 
'TRRFF.1T22AD0033', 'TRRFF.1T22AD0004', 
'TRRFF.1T22AD0038', 'PPRFP.1T22AD0040'}
```